# Laravel filter query results - Only filters base table?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have this method which I use to filter result sets based upon a search query. As you can see, it will get the `Fillable` elements from a model and search against those (possibly not that efficient, but it works and it's quite quick).

```
public static function searchAgainstFillable(&$query, $options, $useRelations = null){
  // Get a list of fillable fields from the model
  if($query->first() != null){
    if(!$useRelations){
      $fillables = $query->first()->getFillable();
      // We could throw an exception here - but just in case oddities have occurred its
      // probably best to just ignore an empty search term.
      if(isset($options['search'])){
        $results = $query->filter(function($setting) use($options, $query, $fillables){
          foreach($fillables as $field){
            if(stripos($setting->{$field}, $options['search']) !== false){
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
      }

      // Finally we want to overwrite the results passed in with the newly
      // filtered results, ready to be presented in the response
      $query = $results;
    }
 }
```

Unfortunately, I've since discovered that when using models that have many layers, this code will only work against the base table and not any other relations. Is there a way I can do this, without running a `foreach` against every relational layer manually? Below is a snippet of my query.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2015-05-18 15:10:59",
    "updated_at": "2015-05-18 15:10:59",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "response_id": 10,
    "user_id": 1,
    "assigned_at": null,
    "follow_up_step_num": 0,
    "is_dropped_out": 0,
    "assigned_user": {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2015-05-15 13:18:22",
        "updated_at": "2015-05-15 13:18:22",
        "email": "REMOVED",
        "firstname": "system",
        "lastname": "user",
        "location_id": 0,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "permissions": [],
        "location_tags": []
    },
    "interactions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2015-05-18 15:10:59",
            "updated_at": "2015-05-18 15:10:59",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "closed_loop_interaction_type_id": 1,
            "interaction_note": "Test Interaction note",
            "closed_loop_processes_id": 1,
            "interaction_type": {
                "id": 1,
                "created_at": "2015-05-18 15:10:59",
                "updated_at": "2015-05-18 15:10:59",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "type": 0,
                "method": "Phone Call (mobile)"
            }
        }
    ],
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "created_at": "2015-02-20 18:48:07",
            "updated_at": "2015-05-18 15:10:58",
            "survey_request_id": 9,
            "response": "Ullam mollitia explicabo accusamus ipsam ad in corrupti. Sed corrupti fugiat veritatis eaque accusantium non eaque deleniti. Doloremque rerum excepturi et adipisci. Et dicta corrupti omnis.",
            "score": 8,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "survey_requests": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Ideally, I want to be able to search against every model that's matched and against any fillable field they may contain.

Comment: Use this https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Builder-searchable-and-more#searchable

Comment: Shameful self promotion? ;) Will take a look, thanks.

Comment: It's simply the best